# Failed to launch IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool via CoreSimulator spawn

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7.1beta

I have an Xcode project which was downloaded from the internet so I don't know which Xcode version was used to write it but the language is Swift 2. I opened it in Xcode 7.1 beta 1 and I get the following compile time error.

**Failed to launch IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool via CoreSimulator spawn**

[image]

I deleted the DerviedData foler, cleaned and build the project several times. Tried converting the project to latest Swift syntax but it says there's nothing to convert.

I'm all outta ideas. Suggestions?

Comment: With Xcode 7.1 now out of Beta i got the same Problem. But surprisingly only for my TodayWidgetTarget. Did you find another Solution then cleaning?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The same happened to me and it was solved by cleaning the project. However, if you cleaned it —as you say you did—, I would try closing and reopening Xcode. Even though it seems stupid, it works more often than not.

Comment: i cleaned, rebuild, closed and opened and did everything, this time it really doesnt go away, like at allllllll

Comment: This is not working for me also. I have tried everything several times. I don't know why it is a correct answer. I am using Xcode 11.7 on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1.

Answer (score 11):

So After Trying a bit i removed the XCassets file form the Copy Bundle Resources, build once without it and then added it again. Solved it for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. My solution was to do the following

1. Clean the Project
2. Quit Xcode
3. Reopen Xcode
4. Build

That got it working for some reason...

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: In my case, after several attempts, I rebooted my machine, reopened Xcode, and cleaned the project.

Answer (score 6):

The above answers are correct.
I have a bit similar approach.

After, I use these steps:

1. Clean the project.
2. Remove your Assets from your project(Remove References). Run the project without assets. Now the project will show some compile errors, these are not very tricky.
3. Run the project, this time project run without your assets and may be chances of crash. This ensures that project will run.
4. Now clean the project and add the assets, now run the project. The project runs successfully.

For me it works. I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

The only correct solution for me that takes only a moment to perform is to delete `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` and all of its contents. Immediately after this the build completes successfully.

I believe the solutions that state to reinstall Xcode, ultimately refresh the CoreSimulator folder, that's why they are successful in resolving the issue.

I started experiencing the error after having upgraded to MacOS Big Sur, while using Xcode 11.6 and Xcode 11.7.

Comment: in my case this didn't work. and when I found a solution to the build issue I had to undo this change to get the simulator to run

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution for those struggling with the above answers.

If you've just restored your machine from a time machine backup (migrating from old to new machine), you may want to re-install Xcode.

It doesn't appear to bring the caches or other important settings across properly from the time machine restore.

I've just taken that; what appears to be a drastic step, but it's worked!

Instructions on how to do so: [Completely reinstall Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122598/completely-reinstall-xcode-9)

-W

Comment: Reinstalling Xcode seems to help (see my own answer to this question). It solved the problem for me on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue tried cleaning and restarting XCODE didn't worked for me,

so I removed xcassets and added the image sets again one by one, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add a step Airman00's answer.

1. List item
2. Clean the Project
3. Quit Xcode
4. Delete derived data
5. Reopen Xcode Build

That got it working for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Update to XCode 7.1.1 from 7.1 solved my problem.

With XCode 7.1 I used Airman00's solution but suddenly it stop working.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you have this type of error in your project then follow these steps:

1. Clean the project
2. And go to storyboard and select any viewController
3. And Run the project again

This will successfully resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have just cleaned `Logs` directory...Then you can try this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /Users/[YourUserName]/Library/Logs
```

Comment: This helped me after accidently messing up my `~/Library` folder

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart my machine to get this to work. Just in case, here are the exact steps I did:

1. Clean project
2. Quick Xcode
3. Delete Derived Data
4. Restart machine
5. Reopen

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with Xcode 11.4 on Catalina 10.15.4.

Rebooting, cleaning project folders, or deleting the derived data directory did not help. What solved the problem for me was to **remove and reinstall Xcode** (I use the AppStore version).

It is possible, that I caused the problem myself by reinstalling macOS 10.15.4 via a Combo-Update.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything . But nothing worked . So i **reinstalled** Xcode . I took some time . But worked

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 14 beta solution**

If you are finding your production Xcode 13 builds aren't working and you have Xcode beta 14 installed you can try this:

- Launch Xcode 14 beta 3
- Open the Platforms preference pane
- Xcode 13 should now work as expected

Source: https://twitter.com/AnaCalinov/status/1545118596820439040