# Completely reinstall Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am writing from my 2016 15" MacBook Pro with macOS 10.12.6 and Xcode 9.1 installed and updated.

Since 9.0 I am experiencing very strange behaviours within Xcode, something that, with v8.x I was not encountering. 
I tried to remove the app, reboot the computer and reinstall it, but with no luck.

I would therefore like to ask you if you could provide me with a detailed list of instructions to follow in order to be able to download and install Xcode 9.1 from the AppStore after having completely wiped out everything that may corrupt its functioning.

Some of the strange behaviours I am witnessing are:
- playgrounds opening in a corrupt state (text styles broken, navigation buttons broken ...)
- wrong SDK loading up on playgrounds creation 
- 'missing labels' when trying to edit the TouchBar's appearance.
- ecc. ...

Please help me solve this.
I need to reinstall it as if I had never installed it before on the computer.

Thank you so much in advance!

yours

NtWM

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this :

1 - remove Xcode from /application folder 
2 - finder bar => go => go to folder > ~/Library/Developer/ 
3 - remove developper folder 
4 - Empty your trash (around 11 giga to delete)
5 - then reinstall Xcode

Comment: Thanks!  Should I reboot the computer between any of these passages? Apple Support sometimes says to reboot before emptying the trash.

Comment: Done everything. It didn't solve it. There seems to be something broken with this release.   Another user reported me having the same issue on a 2015 MacBook Pro.   Now the UIKit error is not anymore there but still the playgrounds are quite broken.