# Failed to launch IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool via CoreSimulator spawn on BigSur

Tags: ios, swift

I've had the same error over and over for 5 times till now, and it's happening randomly on builds. In previous scenarios one of fallowing actions resolved it for me:

1. Clean project filed and delete xcode folder in Library/Developer
2. Reinstallation of xcode and actions from the first point

But my colleagues in project have no problem with this but they are on Catalina not BigSur. Could you please help me find a permanent solution to this problem? I'm using xCode version 11.3.1

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to launch IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool via CoreSimulator spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178032/failed-to-launch-ibcocoatouchimagecatalogtool-via-coresimulator-spawn)

Comment: @ElTomato not really, while it doesn't work for BigSur but what help was deleting all core simulators files. But this makes me configure the simulators for my project every single time. It's just meh